# Display a dynamic XML with angular

Tags: xml, angularjs

I have a Angular app that needs to show a XML for /sitemap route.

At my controller I do a $http.get to retrieve the xml string and them I need to display this XML for this /sitemap route.

I tried several things but I could not figure out how to do this.

Please someone can help me?

Comment: Hi, have you solved this? I'm struggling with the same problem.

Comment: I am also searching for same solution.Did you get any solution?

Answer (score -2):

Just use expressions.

In your controller,

```
$scope.xml= responseData;
```

In your View(HTML) add an expression

```
{{xml}}
```

Comment: But it would output HTML, so it won't work as a sitemap, will it?